# Javascript/Jasmine: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Float64Array

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, qt4, jasmine, emscripten

I'm using rails, pretty new to javascript and setting up my testframework to test my javascripts with `Jasmine`.
Here's the situation:

- I'm using `Viz.js` in my source, which is `Graphviz` compiled to JS with `Emscripten`
- I'm using `jasmine-rails`
- `jasmine` successfully builds from the browser
- however, `jasmine:headless` (which uses Qt webdriver (Im using Qt version 4.8.1)), gives the following error:

> `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Float64Array`
>   
>   which is coming from Viz.js

So my question: can I conclude there are errors in Qt's `Float64Array`? Has emscripten done a messy job?
Is there a workaround?

Comment: Do you know what that ReferenceError means? How does it detect its presence?

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understand your question correctly.
My assumption is that the interpreter hits the line in the code using Float64Array and then noticed Float64Array has not been defined anywhere, which seems valid.

Answer (score 1):

What environment? Which Browser? Which `emscripten` build?

Safari 5 and below does not have `Float64Array`. Update Safari

Also, if you are using `emscripten` `box2d` build, replace `Float64Array` usage in the code by `Float32Array`

EDIT:

Also see this link - https://github.com/kripken/box2d.js/issues/6

Comment: Im using ubuntu 11.04 64-bit. from my browsers (both chrome and firefox) it works fine, but not with the QtWebKit, so given your link, I can conclude this doesnt support Float64Array neither?
AFAIK, graphviz has nothing to do with box2d, but replacing Float64Array by Float32Array... No idea what code I'm changing but ill give it a shot. I'll let you know whether it works

Comment: update: simply changing Float64Array into Float32Array gives more errors and makes it stop working from my browser, so I guess I'll have to dive into the emscripten code / write my own jasmine headless code.
other useful link:
http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/issues/detail?id=607

Comment: :( yup. I hope so. By replacing, I actually wanted to see if some occurrences could give way.